# Referring to "it" in the outer for loop

Tags: loops, kotlin, label

I have a question about accessing the it in the outer loop in kotlin. I am trying to see how many letters differ between two strings. I would like to know is there a way to access the outer for loop with it?

```
fun compute (stringOne: String, stringTwo: String): Int {
  var i = 0
  stringOne.toCharArray().forEach @loop{
    stringTwo.toCharArray().forEach {
      if (it@loop.equals(it))
        i++
    }
   }
  return i
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use named parameters for loops

```
fun compute (stringOne: String, stringTwo: String): Int {
  var i = 0
  stringOne.toCharArray().forEach { char1 ->
    stringTwo.toCharArray().forEach { char2 ->
      if (char1 == char2)
        i++
    }
   }
  return i
}
```